# Multiple instances of a class containing different-sized static arrays

Tags: c++, oop

I need to have multiple instances of a class. Each instance should contain an array of a predefined size. The sizes of the arrays are constant and available in the compile-time, thus I want to allocate them statically.

I have to collect the instances in one "object-array" so I can access them using an iterator. My problems:

1. Static allocation using a constructor argument doesn't work.
2. Instantiation of the objects in the loop doesn't work.

Here's an example code of what I want to do:

```
//Class definition of buffer
class mybuffertype{    
    public:
        mybuffertype(int size);
        int bufsize;
        float *buffer;    
};

//Constructor of buffer
mybuffertype::mybuffertype(int size){
    bufsize=size;
    buffer=new float[bufsize];      //Dynamic allocation
    //float buffer[bufsize];        //This static allocation doesn't work
}

//Class definition of container
class container{    
    public:
        container();
        static const int n_buffers=3;
        const int n_sizes[n_buffers]={4,5,6};
        mybuffertype mybuffers[n_buffers];     
};

//Constructor of container
container::container(void){      
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n_buffers;i++){
        mybuffertype mybuffers[i]= mybuffertype(n_sizes[i]);
    }      
}

//Main
int main(void){    
    container obj;    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<obj.n_buffers;i++){
        printf("Size: %d \t 1st element: %f\n",
              obj.mybuffers[i].size,
              obj.mybuffers[i].buffer[0]);
    }
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: A class must have a single, definitive size at compile-time, so a variably-sized array is out of the question. You could use a class template to generate classes of various sizes, but then you couldn't store them together in an array. Further obscure hacks are possible, but they would probably come at the cost of performance (not to mention, clarity). How far do you want to go to avoid using a plain `std::vector`?

Comment: Do the arrays have to be inside of the objects?

Comment: Yes they have to be inside the objects.

Comment: Why? That would mean each object would have to have a different type.

Comment: You can't have both "they have to be inside the objects" and `mybuffertype mybuffers[n_buffers];`. Pick (at most) one.

Comment: Ok, let's assume, I define them outside of the objects and pass the pointers of the arrays in the runtime. I still need to do that declaration stuff in the loop, because I'm having much more than 3 objects. This is my next problem. I need to declare multiple arrays with constant sizes, where the sizes are given in another array. (like in the example)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: What do you mean by "that declaration stuff in the loop"? You cannot declare multiple objects (that are alive at the same time) with a loop.

Comment: You *can* have e.g. `std::tuple<std::array<double, 3>, std::array<double, 4>, std::array<double, 5>> mybuffers;`, or similar from a compile-time list of sizes

Comment: It has nothing to do with XY problem,this code shall run very efficiently on a slow MCU, which cannot deal with dynamic arrays, nor having enough memory to store big arrays.

Comment: OK, definitely an XY problem then.

Comment: Ok. It's absolutely an XY problem. You won. I still need a solution. Dynamic arrays are no go. Arrays defined outside of the class is acceptable.

Comment: First you need to explain the problem (the X part). So far you've only described your attempt at solving the problem (the Y part), which does not work.

Comment: @Caniko *I need to have multiple instances of a class* -- Maybe you do, maybe you don't.  You're basing this assumption on your attempted solution.  This is the "X" part we should know about.

Answer (score 1):

From a compile-time list of sizes, you can create a collection of (heterogeneously-sized) buffers.

```
template <size_t... Sizes>
class Container
{
    std::tuple<std::array<double, Sizes>...> buffers;
public:
    template<size_t I>
    gsl::span<double> get() { return std::get<I>(buffers); }
    // etc.
};
```

It's slightly more tricky to access a buffer by a runtime index. If you don't care to include the size with the data pointer, switch [`gsl::span<double>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) for `double*`.

```
template <size_t... Sizes>
class Container
{
    std::tuple<std::array<double, Sizes>...> buffers;
    std::array<gsl::span<double>, sizeof...(Sizes)> lookup;

    template <size_t... Idxs>
    array<gsl::span<double>, sizeof...(Sizes)> make_lookup(std::index_sequence<Idxs...>)
    {
        return { get<Idxs>(buffers)... };
    }

public:
    Container() : lookup(make_lookup(std::index_sequence_for<Sizes...>{})) {}

    template<size_t I>
    gsl::span<double> get() { return std::get<I>(buffers); }

    gsl::span<double> operator[](size_t i) { return lookup[i]; }
    // etc.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the static concept with instantiation. You cannot instantiate a static array or class in a constructor.

You could do something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

//Class definition of buffer
class mybuffertype{    
public:
    mybuffertype(int size) {
      bufsize=size;
      buffer=new float[bufsize];      //Dynamic allocation
    }
    virtual ~mybuffertype() {
      delete buffer;
    }
    int bufsize;
    float *buffer;
};

class StaticData {
public:
    StaticData(int n_buffers): n_buffers(n_buffers) {
      mybuffers = new mybuffertype*[n_buffers];
      for (int i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
        mybuffers[i] = new mybuffertype(3+i);
    }
    virtual ~StaticData() {
      for (int i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
        delete mybuffers[i];
      delete [] mybuffers;
    }
    const int n_buffers;
    mybuffertype **mybuffers;
};

//Class definition of container
class MyContainer{
public:
    static StaticData buffers;
};
StaticData MyContainer::buffers(3);

//Main
int main(int argc, char ** argv){    
    for(int i = 0; i < MyContainer::buffers.n_buffers; i++){
        printf("Size: %d \t 1st element: %f\n",
               MyContainer::buffers.mybuffers[i]->bufsize,
               MyContainer::buffers.mybuffers[i]->buffer[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All the static buffers are in a new class `StaticData` which will call the constructor only once as it is declared static in MyContainer. `StaticData` also takes advantage of C++11 array initialization for classes.

Comment: This doesn't answer my questions. The number of buffers is much more then 3, thus I need to declare the arrays in loop. And the buffers are still dynamically declared.

Comment: You confuse declaration and allocation. With `new` you allocate dynamically on the heap. With "statically" I guess you mean to allocate the memory on the stack instead...? You cannot have an array of variable constant size in a class. Does not make sense.

Comment: I updated the code with destructors and so that you can have arbitrary many buffers specified as parameter to `StaticData`.